# Multiple Bibliographies with numeric and alphabetic labels with BibLaTex

Tags: biblatex

I want to use two independent bibliographies with `biblatex`, whereby one is for own publications and the other for the rest. The former should be labeled with letters [A], [B],..., the latter with numbers [1], [2], [3].
I inserted "own" in the own publications in my `.bib` file as a keyword. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mknumalph{#1}}

\defbibenvironment{ownpub}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{albert,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords = {own}
}
@misc{berta,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{cesar,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
own pub: \cite{albert}
other: \cite{berta}
other: \cite{cesar}

\printbibliography[env=bibliography,notkeyword=own]

\printbibliography[env=ownpub,keyword=own,resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

I copied the `numeric.bbx` definition to define a new bib environment "ownpub". It works so far with numeric labels, showing two bibliographies, each starting with [1].
But when I try to switch the `ownpub` environment to alphabetic labels (by the commented `\DeclareFieldFormat`, with `\mknumalph`), the change of `labelnumber` is global and both bibliographies get alphabetic labels.

How can I change just the second bibliography to alphabetic labels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{own}{\mknumalph{#1}}{#1}}
```

to mark the entries with `keyword` `own` with alphabetic labels.

In the MWE below I have removed all modifications that did not change the standard

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{default}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{default}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{own}{\mknumalph{#1}}{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{albert,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  keywords = {own}
}
@misc{berta,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{cesar,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
own pub: \cite{albert}
other: \cite{berta}
other: \cite{cesar}

\printbibliography[notkeyword=own]
\printbibliography[keyword=own,resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: GREAT! Thanks! It works! And how can I change the letter to a capital one?

Comment: @peter Try `\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mknumAlph}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@tempcnta=#1\relax
  \ifnum\blx@tempcnta>702 %
  \else
    \ifnum\blx@tempcnta>26 %
      \advance\blx@tempcnta\m@ne
      \divide\blx@tempcnta26\relax
      \blx@numAlph\blx@tempcnta
      \multiply\blx@tempcnta26\relax
      \blx@tempcnta=\numexpr#1-\blx@tempcnta\relax
    \fi
  \fi
  \blx@numAlph\blx@tempcnta
  \endgroup}
`

Comment: `\def\blx@numAlph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\relax\blx@warning@entry{Value out of range}\number#1\or
  A\or B\or C\or D\or E\or F\or G\or H\or I\or J\or K\or L\or M\or
  N\or O\or P\or Q\or R\or S\or T\or U\or V\or W\or X\or Y\or Z\else
  \blx@warning@entry{Value out of range}\number#1\fi}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{own}{\mknumAlph{#1}}{#1}}`

Comment: Thanks! That works pretty good. But I have a space before the letter in brackets now [ A], how can I fix that?

Comment: @peter Make sure you haven't introduced space when copying the command above and pasting it to your document. The `%` are essential at line ends.

Comment: Ahh, I got it, I inserted one space too much. Thanks guys for that solution in not even 1hour!!

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not now about this, I voted up and accepted your answer, hope that's the way it works :)