# multiple bibliographies style in same document: alpha and numeric

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to have different styles (alphabetic and numeric for two separate bibliographies in my work like in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278564/multiple-bibliographies-with-numeric-and-alphabetic-labels-with-biblatex)).

I compile the file twice: once with Biber, once without it.
After several tries it works but what I get is that for the second bibliography, it is numbered alphabetically (a, b, c, etc.). 
Is there a way to have it in style alpha with part of the author name and year, example: [Ein05]

Comment: Note that the answer to the other question does not actually attempt to make the second bibliography `alphabetic` in the sense of `style=alphabetic`, but rather uses an alphabetic counter for what is still essentially a numeric style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume all the entries you want `numeric` have the keyword `primary`, while all the other entries should be given with `alphabetic` labels.

Then you can use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,labelnumber,defernumbers,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \ifkeyword{primary}
      {\printfield{labelnumber}}
      {\printfield{labelalpha}%
       \printfield{extraalpha}}}}

\defbibenvironment{numericbib}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{aristotle:physics,sigfridsson,worman,aristotle:poetics}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Numeric Bib},keyword=primary,env=numericbib]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Alphabetic Bib},notkeyword=primary,omitnumbers]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

The idea is to branch the `cite` bibmacro on the keyword. We also need to request numeric citations (via the `labelnumber` option), but we drop the numbers for the alphabetic bibliography with `omitnumbers`. The numeric bibliography gets its own format so it can display the labels properly.

For `biblatex` versions >= 3.4 (not yet released, but can be tested as a development version) you will need to change `prefixnumber` to `labelprefix` in the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted. But I still have a problem. If i don't put `\printbibheading`, I get the header of the last chapter for the bibliographie. If I put it , I get an empty page with just the title BIBLIOGRAPHIE then the header BIBLIOGRAPHIE Bibliographie for both types of referencesAlso I am getting a footer also with BIBLIOGRAPHIE  which I don't need.  I want for the first type to have Numeric Bib and Alphabetic Bib in the header and no footer or extra page .

Comment: Had to remove `heading=subbibliography`from `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Numeric Bib},keyword=primary,env=numericbib]` and the next one. Now it works fine for the header and footer but  I still get the empty page with only the title bibliographie (references) in it.

Comment: @etudiant_is That probably has to do with your documentclass, you can open a new question with an MWE about it.

Comment: Ok, but I was not getting that page before. But I was not using either the `\printbibheading` either

Comment: @etudiant_is It will have to do with how your documentclass interacts with `biblatex`'s heading commands, as you can see in the MWE above it is not just that `biblatex` randomly adds blank pages. So to investigate this further we need to see the code you actually use.

Comment: I removed  `\printbibheading`and `heading=subbibliography`and now I have no longer the blank page nor the wrong header. It is all solved.