# alpha style for owned publications and numeric for others

Tags: biblatex

I'd like to do the exact opposite of what is solved in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301412/multiple-bibliographies-style-in-same-document-alpha-and-numeric). Namely, I'd like the bib entries with a "primary" keyword (my own works) to have alphabetic citation style, while all other entries have numeric-comp style. I cannot just switch keywords in the answer of the post cited, because I really want to use the feature of numeric-comp (I want to call \usepackage[style=numeric-comp,...]{biblatex})

Trying to follow what is done in that post I would need to write a \defbibenvironment{} function that implements alphabetic citations, but I don't know how to do that. Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `numeric-comp` is a pretty complex style that has to do a lot of work to get the whole "comp" feature going. If some entries don't have numeric labels, it's going to be a pain to make sure that they don't interfere with this.