# Sort Bibliography by own / notown and partial added character/initials with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, ieee-style, bibliographystyle

for a thesis, I would like to cite in a way, that my own publications appear as the first entries with added initials, before continuing with the other bibentries. For example:

*Some text with a non-own cite [4], an own-cite [1AB] and another one [2AB] and a another non-own cite [5].*

**Bibliography**

[1AB] own Book1

[2AB] own Paper2

[3AB] own Book3

[4] Book 5

[5] Book 6

...

Separting the two parts in separate bibliographies is no problem with

```
\printbibliography[keyword=own]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own]
```

But I want both sets of entries in a single list and the own publications should hold the first numbers no matter, when they show up in the text. Within the respective own and non-own citations, sorting should again be based on appearance in the text.

I am using the ieee style within biblatex. Is this behavior somehow possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Declare your own label format:

```latex
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\ifkeyword{own}{{#1}AB}{#1}}
```

Then call `\printbibliography` twice:

```latex
\printbibliography[keyword=own]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own, heading=none]
```

If you want to reset the numbering for non-own references, add `resetnumbers=true` to the second `\printbibliography`.

This answer is based on [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278566/124229) to a similar question.